# Jenkins build trigger ways

Tags: jenkins

I have added job A,B and C in jenkins. Job B dependent on Job A , Job C is dedepdent on Job A and Job B.
If I trigger build on Job A, Job B and Job C will start building also as they are dependent on A.
But Job C will get build 2 times, because dependency A -> B -> C and A -> C.
So how can I restrict Job C to build only once ?

Comment: Why don't you make the dependencies like this: ```A - > B``` and ```B - > C```?

Comment: Because C needs .jar file of both projects A and B also.

Comment: But B cannot start without A first, can it?

Comment: A,B,C jobs can start independently.

Comment: Use Build flow plugin

Comment: ```job B dependent on Job A , Job C is dedepdent on Job A and Job B``` you make me confused.

Comment: Simple dude .. A <- B <- C   and A <- C .. these 2 are dependency..So here C will execute 2 times right ?.   That I want to avoid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can block a build of job `C` when upstream project is building. Hit the checkbox under Advanced Project Options:

[image]

Having this, build of job `C` won't start before finishing a build of job `B`. As it's not possible to have two or more builds of the same job in the build queue, job `C` will be triggered once.

**Note**: this is a tricky way. Please be sure that you can't use only `A` -> `B` -> `C` relationship.

Comment: Dude this trick is working. I tried with A <- B <- C <- D  and A <- D for both dependency D job built only once. Still in my workspace I am using lot of projects so no idea how dependencies will be.   What do you mean by "Note:" and for what condition this may fail ?

Comment: @sandy_ws Actually i am not a fun of blocking a build, because headed into few Jenkins bugs. Here, `C` will wait if `B` is in a build queue.  If, for example, node of `B` is unavailable, both jobs will wait for a build.This could be undesirable. I didn't find any other unexpected behavior.

Answer (score 0):

```
Use post build action - > Trigger parametrized build on other project
```

Install [this plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Trigger+Plugin) to get this option.

Comment: another way:   Use Build Flow plugin or Multijob plugins - https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+Flow+Plugin, https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Multijob+Plugin